# Linux device interaction

Tags: operating-system, linux-device-driver, hardware-interface

In Linux, is it possible for an application interacts with hardware device( for instance: camera) without using /dev/* device file?So I mean is possible to use hardware device without making or “using” /dev/* device file?

Comment: Possible? Sure. Usual? Not really. You could technically have any kind of interface between the device driver and userspace, it's up to the driver to choose how to implement it, but they usually all follow the same conventions.

Comment: Ok, can you provide me an example of interface? Do you mean character file? So if I understood well, I can create another character file that binds driver device and hardware device …is it right? But if in /proc/devices I don’t find any kind of driver that handles camera, how is it possible to use camera?